# How to check today date is first day of the current month

Tags: java

How to find out if the today date is the first day of the current month.
Say, today is 24/05/2015 but it is not first day of the month.
what is the best way to get the output.

Comment: `if (day == 1) { `...

Comment: get the date and check if day ==1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the "day" part and compare it to 1:

```
if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1) {
    System.out.println ("Today is the first day of the month");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is say 1 of the month, like so:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if (day == 1) {
    // first day of the month.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [joda](http://www.joda.org/time):

```
boolean isFirstDay = new DateTime(dateObject).getDayOfMonth() == 1;
if(isFirstDay) {
   // do whatever
} else {
   // whatever 
}
```